# Chern-Weil theory on some noncompact groups, and characteristic classes in differential cohomology

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, invariant-theory, characteristic-classes, differential-cohomology

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\newcommand{\HdR}{H_{\mathrm{dR}}} \newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}}
\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak g}$I have a specific question about invariant polynomials for some Lie groups,
motivated by a question from differential cohomology. I'll begin with the specific question and then provide the
general context.

Specific question: if $G$ is a Lie group, let $\Sym^\bullet(\g^*)$ denote the algebra of $G$-invariant polynomials
on $\g$, where $G$ acts on $\g$ by the adjoint action. This is contravariant in $G$. **Are the following three maps
isomorphisms, and if so, where is a good reference to read about/cite this fact?**

1. $\Sym^\bullet(\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb R))^{\mathit{GL}(n, \mathbb R)}\to\Sym^\bullet(\mathfrak o(n))^{O(n)}$
   induced by the inclusion $O(n)\hookrightarrow\mathit{GL}(n, \mathbb R)$.
2. Letting $\mathit{GL}_0(n, \mathbb R)\subset \mathit{GL}(n, \mathbb R)$ denote the connected component of the
   identity, the map $\Sym^\bullet(\mathfrak{gl}_0(n, \mathbb R))^{\mathit{GL}_0(n, \mathbb
   R)}\to\Sym^\bullet(\mathfrak{so}(n))^{\mathit{SO}(n)}$ induced by the inclusion
   $\mathit{SO}(n)\hookrightarrow\mathit{GL}_0(n, \mathbb R)$.
3. $\Sym^\bullet(\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb C))^{\mathit{GL}(n, \mathbb C)}\to\Sym^\bullet(\mathfrak u(n))^{U(n)}$
   induced by the inclusion $U(n)\hookrightarrow\mathit{GL}(n, \mathbb C)$.

---

This question came up for me in the context of Chern-Weil theory. This is a machine that takes in a $G$-invariant
polynomial and a principal $G$-bundle $P\to M$ with connection and builds a closed differential form on $M$, hence
a de Rham cohomology class (which doesn't depend on the connection). Letting $G$ be $O(n)$, $\mathit{SO}(n)$, or
$U(n)$ gives rise to the usual Pontrjagin, Euler, and Chern classes of vector bundles through an associated vector
bundle construction: when $G$ is compact, the Chern-Weil map $\Sym^\bullet(\g^*)\to H^{2\bullet}(BG;\mathbb R)$ is an
isomorphism. Using the compact groups amounts to choosing a metric on your vector bundle, but this is OK: the maps
$BO(n)\hookrightarrow B\mathit{GL}(n, \mathbb R)$ (etc.) are homotopy equivalences, so picking a metric doesn't
change what characteristic classes are available.

Cheeger-Simons lifted this construction to differential cohomology: if you have an integer lift of your de Rham
cohomology class, you obtain a characteristic class of principal $G$-bundles with connection in differential
cohomology $\check c(P, \nabla)\in \check H{}^\bullet(M;\Z)$, hence also differential Pontrjagin, Euler, and Chern classes
for vector bundles with connection (which can depend on the connection!).

However, there is a subtlety here. If we use the compact groups, we know the Chern-Weil map is an isomorphism, so
we obtain Pontrjagin, Chern, and Euler classes — but for vector bundles with a metric, and *only for
connections which are compatible with the metric*. If we use the noncompact groups, we get characteristic classes
for vector bundles with arbitrary connection, but a priori we don't know that we get all Pontrjagin, Euler, and
Chern classes: differential cohomology is not homotopy-invariant in general.

This seems like the kind of invariant-theoretic computation that has been done before, and if so, I want to
attribute it correctly, but I haven't been able to find a reference.

Comment: Theorem 3.79 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3961.pdf seems to treat this matter for "Lie groups with finitely many components".

Comment: This https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3927.pdf might be relevant, too.

Comment: The case of a compact group is treated in Section 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410013v2

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think the Pfaffian doesn't extend to be invariant under the orientation preserving general linear group. At least, check that first, I suggest.